# How to merge SQL Select queries?

Tags: sql

I have three queries executed consistently:

```
SELECT TOP 1 max(value) FROM tableA
where site = 18
    and (CAST(DATEADD(s,t_stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) >= '2017-2-1'
    and CAST(DATEADD(s,t_stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) <= '2017-2-28')
Group by CAST(DATEADD(s,t_stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE)
order by CAST(DATEADD(s,t_stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) DESC;

SELECT TOP 1 max(value) FROM tableA
where site = 3
    and (CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) >= '2017-2-1'
    and CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) <= '2017-2-28')
Group by CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE)
order by CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) DESC;

SELECT TOP 1 max(value) FROM tableA
where site = 4
    and (CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) >= '2017-2-1'
    and CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) <= '2017-2-28')
Group by CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE)
order by CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) DESC;
```

I want to combine this three queries into one and query sites 18, 3, 4 via one select, but I don't see how. Please advise how to merge this 3 queries into one.
**Any help will be appreciated!**

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to accomplish.  Sample data and desired results would help, as would an appropriate database tag.

Comment: Don't aimlessly add SQL related tags. [tag:tsql] is used by SQL Server, not [tag:myself] or [tag:postgresql] and [tag:mysql-workbench] is for MySQL only (as the name suggests)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to want the maximum value for three different sites on the last day in February that has their data.

If so, this is simpler:

```
select site_id, max(value)
from (select t.*,
             dense_rank() over (partition by site order by tstamp / (1000 * 24 * 60 * 60) desc) as seqnum
      from t
      where tstamp >= datediff(second, '1970-01-01', '2020-02-01') * 1000 and
            tstamp < datediff(second, '1970-01-01', '2020-02-29') * 1000 and
            site_id in (18, 3, 4)
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Actually, February in 2020 has 29 days.  Perhaps you want the entire month; if so, then use `'2020-03-01'` for the second comparison.

Note that the manipulations on the date/time values are only on the "constant" side.  This allows the query to use an index on `tstamp` if an appropriate index is available.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the analytical function `row_number` in your existing query as follows:

```
Select * from
(SELECT max(value), site, 
       Row_number() over (partition by site order by CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) desc) as rn FROM tableA
where site in (4,18,3
    and (CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) >= '2017-2-1'
    and CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE) <= '2017-2-28')
Group by CAST(DATEADD(s,stamp/1000,'1970-01-01 00:00:00') as DATE), site)
Where rn = 1
```